# How to get the position of a table view's subview before it's displayed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I've tried searching for this on SO, but no luck finding something that works for my situation.

Here is my hierarchy and what I'm trying to do:

```
//     ->  view
//     -> ->  myLabel           //I'd like to have this match center.x with...
//     -> ->  tableView
//     -> -> ->  tableViewCell
//     -> -> -> ->  UIStackView
//     -> -> -> -> ->  mySwitch    //...this, before everything appears
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? All help is very appreciated. Thanks!

---

EDIT: This code works on the positioning, but doesn't run before it appears. It runs when a cell has to get loaded/reused, so it first appears in the wrong spot:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as? myCell {
        cell.configureCell(myArray[indexPath.row])
        let centerPoint = cell.mySwitch.convertPoint(cell.mySwitch.center, toView: self.view)
        myLabel.center.x = centerPoint.x - (myLabel.frame.width / 2)
        return cell
    } else {
       return myCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, it's programmed in myCell.swift (the controller for the tableViewCell subclass I'm using)

Comment: Do you know the position of the Switch inside the cell?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention: I was able to get the global position of the switch, but I don't know where to implement the code that changes the label's position so it happens before things appear. I'll update my question with the code I've found to work, plus the stack view I left out in the hierarchy just in case

Comment: @SeanC.Li if you know the position of the Switch before hand you can use autolayout to set the position of the Label so everything will be correctly displayed in place before the view actually appears. You shouldn't tight the Label to the Switch because the cells are handled by the TableView and recycled and appear and disappear at a different time than the rest of the views in the screen.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have my table change width dynamically depending on screen size. That part works. Every cell in the table has a switch (positioned the same using autolayout), and I just want to give the switches a title at the top so the user knows what they do. I don't mind running the code every time the cells appear, if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i understand your question, but you can try to use

> -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

you can get the refer to cell and use cell.yourSwitch.frame.origin for position

Comment: I tried that function and plopped my code from above into it (starting at the 'let centerPoint' line), but it won't build, saying "Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'mySwitch'". Is there another way?

Comment: you must create a custom class that extends UITableViewCell, assign this class to your cell and then create an IBOutlet of your switch in your cell definition. Then you can access to it with cell.yourSwitch and so get the position values.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Thanks everyone for the help. For anyone interested, I gave up and resorted to using the size classes in interface builder, though it would have been more ideal to do it programmatically (Keeps things cleaner IMO, as opposed to having to tailor it to each size class. Now the two items aren't actually constrained to each other, I positioned them manually). Leaving this question open for any other readers who would like to comment or read!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments this is what you should do (although I don't recommended because it will affect the performance of your app)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    //Option 1
    (cell as! MyCell).mySwitch...

    //Option 2
    let cell: MyCell = cell as! MyCell
    cell.mySwitch...
}
```

But if I understood correctly and all the switches are positioned at the same level in every cell all you need to do is position the label in the same way you positioned everything else so it will look aligned with the switches without the need of actually tying them together.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the input. I want to say I tried something very similar, but maybe what would have fixed it is the way you're casting cell as! MyCell. Otherwise it seems similar to what the other person has suggested and what I tried, but it wouldn't build, saying that `cell` didn't contain `mySwitch`. Either way I just resorted to IB and manually made sure they look like they match center.x in every size class as you also suggest. Not as ideal or fun to me since it doesn't futureproof the label, but it definitely did the job. Thanks!!

Comment: P.S. The app is iphone and ipad compatible which is why I wanted to do it programmatically if you catch my drift haha.

Comment: @SeanC.Li if you are using auto layout you won't have any trouble displaying the screen in an iPad or any iPhone because its all positioned properly according to the constraints (thats why is better to use constraints instead of frames, because it takes out all the math behind the positioning of the views). You could even change the constraint if needed to depending on the device by using `UIDevice.current().userInterfaceIdiom == (.pad OR .phone)` Hope it helped and if not and still are looking to solve it, I'm glad to help.